# Continuation of execution and commit for correctly executed statments

Tags: postgresql

Here's below my procedure. Inside u find a loop. Target is if any of single loop execution will throw exception i don't want to stop the process and want to continue and `commit` each loop query which was executed succesfully. Therefore i placed exception catch inside loop. As u can see i also got a `commit` at the end and some `begin/end` blocks. My question is whether did i correctly or maybe i should put additional `commit` inside `begin/end` inside the loop (just after `execute mysql`;)? Thank you in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare

mysql text;
tb_name text;

myTables CURSOR for
    SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema='dist';
    
begin
    begin 
        call DoSomeJob();
                  
                  
        for tb in myTables loop         
            tb_name := tb;
           
           begin                                         
                    mysql := format('delete from %I where somecol=2', tb_name);
                    execute mysql; 
                           
            exception
                  when others then      
                        raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
            end ;
        end loop;
       

        call doOtherJob();     
       
    exception 
       when others then 
            raise notice 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. '
           'Transaction was rolled back';
            raise notice '%: %', SQLSTATE, sqlerrm;

   end ;
    
commit; 
end;
$procedure$
;
```

**UPDATE:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare
mysql text;
tb_name text;
myTables CURSOR for
    SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema='dist';
    
begin

        begin
           call DoSomeJob();
        exception 
            when others then 
                raise notice 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. '
               'Transaction was rolled back';
                raise notice '%: %', SQLSTATE, sqlerrm;
        end;

        RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR test';
                  
        for tb in myTables loop         
            tb_name := tb;
           
           begin                                         
                    mysql := format('delete from %I where somecol=2', tb_name);
                    execute mysql; 
                           
            exception
                  when others then      
                        raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
            end ;
        end loop;
       
        begin
            call doOtherJob();     
        exception 
            when others then 
                raise notice 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. '
               'Transaction was rolled back';
                raise notice '%: %', SQLSTATE, sqlerrm;
        end;
    
commit; 
end;
$procedure$;
```

Comment: Avoid catching exceptions indiscriminately with `WHEN OTHERS`, it tends to mask problems. Don't name a variable `mysql`, it may cause PostgreSQL to misbehave.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thx for priceless advice i will change that. What about original question?

Comment: I cannot answer the question with confidence. It looks ok at first glance, but I wonder why you `DELETE` rather than `TRUNCATE`, and I wonder about the purpose of the outer exception handler.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorrym there is some condition based on what i delete therefore not truncate. U think no additional COMMIT; required just after execute mysql;  ? Does last COMMIT; just enough at the end?

Comment: It depends on what your purpose is...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I made some test. Can u take a look on main post UPDATE section, when i `RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR test';` then `DoSomeJob` is not commited. Why is that?

Comment: I am not going to comment on this any more, and I have voted to close. This is nothing personal, but I'd say that questions that show a wad of code and ask "is this code ok" have a lack of focus and are impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I explain you how to works PostgreSQL transactions in procedures.
Firstly

1. begin is a - "begin transaction";
2. end is a  - "commit transaction"

And when you using transaction in another transaction (sub transactions) when your first level transaction rollbacked then all sub transactions also will be rollbacked.
For example:

```
begin --block call2
        begin --block call1
            call1; 
        exception
            when others then      
            raise notice 'error call1'
        end;    
    call2; 
exception
    when others then      
    raise notice 'error call2'
end;
```

Here when `call2` failed then `call1` also be failed. Because block `call1` is in the  block `call2`

And on your procedure - when `doOtherJob()` will be fail then all your inserted data will fail to. For solving this problem you can write your procedure as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare
mysql text;
tb_name text;
myTables CURSOR for
    SELECT table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema='dist';
    
begin
        call DoSomeJob();
                  
        for tb in myTables loop         
            tb_name := tb;
           
           begin                                         
                    mysql := format('delete from %I where somecol=2', tb_name);
                    execute mysql; 
                           
            exception
                  when others then      
                        raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
            end ;
        end loop;
       
        begin
            call doOtherJob();     
        exception 
            when others then 
                raise notice 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. '
               'Transaction was rolled back';
                raise notice '%: %', SQLSTATE, sqlerrm;
        end;
    
commit; 
end;
$procedure$;
```

You can set for block `DoSomeJob()` to the same logic.

Comment: additionally in your last code if i also make DoSomeJob within begin/end and exception. Having that if i understood well then if anything will fail entire procedure will continue, am i right? P.S Why then u also kepts 'commit;' at the end of procedure?

Comment: `BEGIN` and `END` do *not* enclose a transaction in PL/pgSQL. It is the `EXCEPTION` clause that makes a block represent a subtransaction.

Comment: @Ramin Faracov I made some test. Can u take a look on main post UPDATE section, when i `RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR test';` then `DoSomeJob` is not commited. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

When using procedures in PostgreSQL, especially about transactions, you need to know and understand some details well. I will now explain to you the important details and you will understand how it works.

begin - this is start transaction (always)

exception

end - this is not always `commit-transaction`, because if exception is created then `end` will be `rollback-transaction` if else `end` will be `commit-transaction`

And remember that: each block `end` affects only its own block `begin`

At the same time, pay attention to this:

During rollback process, all other `begin-exception-end` blocks which is under between the `begin` block and the `exception` block will be rollback.

Please execute this block and view result: `select * from table test1`

```
DO
$body$
begin   
    CREATE TABLE test1 (
        id int4 NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT test1_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

    begin  -- block 1                                        
        insert into test1 (id) values (1);             
    exception
        when others then      
        raise notice 'exception ';
    end;

    begin -- block 2                                         
        insert into test1 (id) values (error);             
    exception
        when others then      
        raise notice 'exception ';
    end;
           
    begin -- block 3                                       
        insert into test1 (id) values (3);             
    exception
        when others then      
        raise notice 'exception ';
    end;

    begin --block 4                                      
        begin -- block 5                                        
            insert into test1 (id) values (5);             
        exception
            when others then      
            raise notice 'exception ';
        end;    
        insert into test1 (id) values (error);      
    exception
        when others then      
        raise notice 'exception ';
    end;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

1. `block 1` - success execute (success insert 1) - commit
2. `block 2` - execute with error (no inserted record) - rollback
3. `block 3` - execute success (success insert 3) - commit
4. `block 5` - execute success (success insert 5) - commit
5. `block 4` - execute with error (no inserted record) - rollback

Since `block 5` is inside `block 4` so `block 5` already rollbacked

```
Result: select * from test1
1
3
```